# How to set a Gtk Box to have two children

Tags: gtk, gtkmm, hbox

I have a Gtk::HBox which should contain two elements only. However, the constructor new Gtk::HBox() creates a box with three elements, so when I display my window, there is an ugly space where Gtk expects me to put a third element.

I thought the Gtk api would provide an easy way to set the number of children, but it doesn't. Since Glade allows me to create an HBox with two elements, I guess it can be done, but now I need to do it with c++ code.

It's very strange that I can't find answers in Google for such a simple question, I must be missing something... any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your calls to `Gtk::HBox::pack_start()`?

Comment: Are you sure there are 3 items at construction time? Could it instead be an issue with your expand/fill parameters when adding your two items?

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with expand/fill. I was calling pack_start(child, false, false, 0). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `true` in the `expand` and `fill` arguments to [Gtk::Box::pack_start()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Box.html#a31aa59034a669239c4b99a9ced5742d6):

```
hbox.pack_start(child, true, true);
```

Or call its [simpler override](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Box.html#ae1a2ca6c5de8ad4442ed93c2c20eec87):

```
hbox.pack_start(child);
```